# Spring repository saving objects with attributes that are made using subclasses

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

So i have the VoteEvent class that is a a subclass of the Event class. The Event class looks like this:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Event {
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="timeSlot")
    private String timeSlot;
```

The VoteEvent class looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "vote_events")

public class VoteEvent extends Event implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "upVotes")
    private Integer upVotes = 0;
```

In my user object, I have an array of VoteEvents so that I know which events a specific user as upvoted. In my frontend, I pass in an array of vote events that have the timeslot and name attributes when I update the user upvoted events. However when I do:

```
return new ResponseEntity<User>(userRepository.save(_user), HttpStatus.OK);
```

, the response is correct and the user array of vote events have the name and time slot attributes, but when I look in the database, the user array of vote events have the null name and time slot attributes. So, whenever I save an object using a spring repository that has objects that are constructed with subclasses, they lose the superclass attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code, it's working fine for me.

```
package com.apimanager.metadata;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;

@Data
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@MappedSuperclass
public class Event {
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "timeSlot")
    private String timeSlot;
}
```

For VoteEvent and Event kindly provide **`@SuperBuilder`** and **`@RequiredArgsConstructor`**. May be it's due to those property are not accessible in **`VoteEvent`** object

```
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "vote_events")
public class VoteEvent extends Event implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "upVotes")
    private Integer upVotes = 0;
```